# SQL select past 5 years data

Tags: sql

I am trying to extract 3 years of data. I am trying to link it into Tableau and want it to auto update  the last 3 years. So, I was wondering if somebody could help me correct my statement here.

```
Select * 
From tb1 1
Where Year = dateadd(year, -3, getdate())
```

I only get the headers but it shows no values.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Clarify your request.  It is actually quite ambiguous.  Do you want the last 3/5 *calendar* years?  The last 3/5 years to the date?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this below query

```
Select * 
From tb1 1
Where Year >= dateadd(year, -3, getdate())
```